# Update a Datetime variable with particular hour value

Tags: datetime, blueprism

I need a datetime - yesterday 9 PM

I tried like below, but it is set as 12 AM only.

```
AddDays(Today(), -1) + (MakeTimeSpan(0, 21, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set datetime to yesterday 9PM you can go with something like this

`ToDateTime(AddDays(Today(),-1) & " " & MakeTime (21,0,0))`

Comment: I don't see ToDateTime in blue prism Date functions. Where can I access full list of functions possible with data types? any documentation?

Comment: ToDateTime is under Conversion group. All available BP functions are divided into groups and listed in Calculation stage properties (on the left side). You can always use BP help (F1) and search there if you need more information.